# Intermittently receiving 404 error after wildfly server running and project deployed

Tags: jboss, wildfly

For some reason, I keep receiving a 404 error every other time a launch my web application using wildfly 10.1.0.  What seems to be happening is the app is deploying before the server starts running.

Does anyone know how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Which mode standalone or domain?

Comment: ... and how are you deploying the application?

Comment: I am using standalone mode.